# Step by step guide for building a login using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know of a simple tutorial that provides a step by step guide for building a signin page to validate a username and password using Rails/MySQL. Came across a couple online but they're either very old or difficult to follow:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-build-an-unobtrusive-login-system-in-rails/
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top

Thanks,

O.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use an "out-of-the-box" solution?

Comment: Yep, because i'd like to learn what going on behind the scenes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password

Answer (score 1):

I like Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

You can skip to chapter 5 for starting the authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

**Devise** is a full-featured authentication solution which handles all of the controller logic and form views for you. Learn how to set it up in [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).